# How to locate an element with part of the id in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright, e2e

I have an HTML like this

```
<div class="tox-sidebar-wrap">
    <div class="tox-edit-area">
        <iframe id="_tinymce-0qcgf3evlihj_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
            title="Rich Text Area" class="tox-edit-area__iframe">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the `id` of the `iframe` is dynamically generated. I'd like to locate it in Playwright, I think maybe I can use part of its id: `_tinymce-`, but not sure how to do it?

Playwright code generator gave me this:
 `await page.frameLocator('[id="_tinymce-0qcgf3evlihj_ifr"]').locator('#tinymce').fill('test');`

Comment: Try `page.frameLocator('[id*="_tinymce-"]')`

Comment: A bit more precise: `'[id^="_tinymce-"]'`. That said, there's usually a better way to select than CSS, so providing the actual page and/or full context is ideal.

Comment: I'd try [`page.getByTitle("Rich Text Area")`](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-title)